# How to separate two macro variables dataset name with an underscore?

Tags: sas, identifier, sas-macro

I'm trying to separate a dataset name which is created by two macro variables by an underscore, but it gives me an error in %macro create_table.

```
%macro create_tables;
* NOTE THE DOUBLE AMPERSAND! *;
data &&_produto&i_&&_mes_char&j;
```

I tried to use a dot in the end of the first macro variable but didnt work as expected. how could I solve this situation?

```
%macro create_tables;
    * NOTE THE DOUBLE AMPERSAND! *;
    data &&_produto&i_&&_mes_char&j;
        set aux_base_defaults;
        if fim_mes = &&_fim_mes&j and cod = &&_id_produto&i;
    run;
%mend create_tables;

*------------------------------------------*;
* DEFINE MACRO VARIABLES *;
*------------------------------------------*;
proc sql;

create table produtos_a_considerar as
select b.sigla, a.cod
    from (select distinct cod
                from aux_base_defaults
            group by cod) a
inner join ecl.referencia_produtos b on b.id_produto = a.cod;

quit;

data _null_;
    set produtos_a_considerar;
    call symput( '_produto' || left(trim(_N_)) , trim(sigla));
    call symput( '_id_produto' || left(trim(_N_)) , cod);
    call symput( '_obs_produto' , _N_ );
run;

data _null_;
    set dim_fim_mes;
    call symput( '_fim_mes' || left(trim(_N_)) , fim_mes );
    call symput( '_mes_char' || left(trim(_N_)) , substr(mes_char,1,7));
    call symput( '_obs_fim_mes' , _N_ );
run;

*-----------------------------------------*;
* SUBMIT EXAMPLE5 FOR EACH DATASET *;
*-----------------------------------------*;
%macro loop;
    %do i=1 %to &_obs_produto;  
        %do j=1 %to &_obs_fim_mes;
            %create_tables;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend loop;
%loop;
```

Comment: You might have a cleaner presentation of work flow learning how to perform `BY` group processing.  Once you get that down you will not have to compute each combination of the by variables and process each combinations subset thereof.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed? I didn´t get it

Comment: List the variables in the table and describe how they are linked.  It seems like you are placing the distinct key values of two tables in a large number of macro symbols, and then nested looping them to create a separate table for each combination.  Do you really need separate tables with the produto and mes_char values in the table names ?   In SQL, an inner join does essentially the same join processing all at once and the data can be used more simply downstream with appropriate `BY` and `WHERE` statements.

Comment: Yes, Richard, i need each table with produto and mes_char values, cause i'm trying to compute Loss given default curves for each produto and each mes_char. But i got your ideia thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you need 2 dots - first to separate your loop variable from the underscore, then another to separate the resulting left macro var from the underscore after resolving the first lot of ampersands.

It is often helpful to write a minimal example to verify that this sort of thing works the way that you are expecting. E.g.

```
%let mvar1 = foo;
%let mvar2 = bar;

%let i = 1;
%let j = 2;

%put &&mvar&i.._&&mvar&j;
```

Output:

```
foo_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need more periods.  Essentially one for every pass that the macro processor needs to make in order to fully resolve the macro variable references.

But it is probably way easier to re-structure your program so you don't need to worry about it.

```
%local dsname ;
%let dsname = &&_produto&i
%let dsname = &dsname._&&_mes_char&j;
data &dsname ;
 ...
```